# Will the Nginx cache manager clean out files when approaching the limit of the disk?

Tags: caching, nginx

We're planning on updating our Nginx cache duration and I'm just going through the documentation to make sure nothing catches us out when I came across the following:

> *max_size* sets the upper limit of the size of the cache (to 10 gigabytes in this example). It is optional; not specifying a value allows the cache to grow to use all available disk space. When the cache size reaches the limit, a process called the cache manager removes the files that were least recently used to bring the cache size back under the limit.

Source: https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/

We've mounted a separate HDD which will be used solely for the cache and 
I'm tempted to not specify the `max_size` property so that it will just use the available space (as per the above) but it doesn't specify whether the cache manager will handle the clean up when the "limit" is the implied size of the disk.

Does anyone know whether the cache manager will handle this or should we be setting the `max_size` (to the size of the HDD) just to be on the safe side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Nginx sources show that the file cache manager is a small [function](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/b5d7d3f024f587682e320d891e52e693939a5f14/src/http/ngx_http_file_cache.c#L1890) that is called by the cache manager process. It [checks](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/b5d7d3f024f587682e320d891e52e693939a5f14/src/http/ngx_http_file_cache.c#L1912) if the current cache size is larger than the `max_size`, and if it is, tries to delete the last cache node from both the internal queue and the disk. And unless you redefine it in the configuration file, the `max_size` is simply [set](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/b5d7d3f024f587682e320d891e52e693939a5f14/src/http/ngx_http_file_cache.c#L2204) with a large platform-dependent constant [value](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/b5d7d3f024f587682e320d891e52e693939a5f14/auto/types/sizeof#L58).

So it would appear that the cache manager does not do anything fancy, like trying to determine the disk size. It merely uses a large constant value and leaves it to you to worry about the consequences.

So, if you won't set the `max_size` explicitly, you might eventually end up with tons of [errors](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/b5d7d3f024f587682e320d891e52e693939a5f14/src/http/ngx_http_file_cache.c#L1384) and misbehaving cache.

Also note that the cache manager lives in a separate process and it may not notice in time that the cache size went beyond the limit. For this reason it would be wise to set the `max_size` with a value at least 100 Mb less than the actual HDD size.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Your answer is definitely in line with what I thought might be the case so I'll set the limit just below the HDD capacity